# How do google know the date of the website

Tags: html, web, sitemap

When I search for something on Google, I noticed that some website have a date shown but some have not. I searched it for a while but didn't find the answer.

How does Google know the date that your website page was published? Is the date info contained in a `meta` tag or by the sitemap?

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95792/how-to-get-google-to-display-the-published-date-of-blog-post-in-the-search-resul

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has all kinds of technology that crawls sites for relevant information. Dates of websites would be key pieces of information. Some people still do meta tagging in the heading of their code for SEO. They may put the date in their meta tagging.

Answer (score 0):

i use json for doing that and its work for me this the sample code you can change it with your date(it have some extera parameter also)

```
    <!-- JSON-LD markup generated by Google Structured Data Markup Helper. -->
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Article",
  "name" : "your name",
  "headline" : "headline",
  "author" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "name"
  },
  "datePublished" : "2017-04-22 01:38:22",
  "dateModified" : "2017-04-22 01:38:22",
  "image" : { "@type": "ImageObject", "url" : "https://....",
            "height" : "352px",
            "width" :"800px",
            "thumbnail" : "https://..."
            },
  "articleBody" : "",
    "url" : "",
    "publisher" : {
    "@type" : "Organization",
    "name" : "",
    "logo" : { "@type": "ImageObject", "url": "https://...."}
  }
}
</script>
```